# Avoiding duplicates in drupal 6 views2-relationship-results

Tags: drupal-6, duplicates, drupal-views, relationships

I'm trying to build a list using drupal6, views and node reference.
The list should be look like:

- vehicle 1

  - feature 1
  - feature 2
  - feature 3
  - extra 1
- vehicle 2
- vehicle 3

The `vehicle` is a custom node-type, `feature` and `extra` also. In my view I'm listing all `vehicle`-node (as fields), added relationships to `feature` and `extra` nodes and added the reference-fields.

Now I'm getting the desired list. But when the displayed node contains more than one relationship of the same type (see `feature` in `vehicle 1` in list above) I'm getting one result line per relationship (`vehicle 1` get displayed three times).

Is there any way to group these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some longish time searching and trying to implement custom theming solutions to combine the duplicated results, I found a [similar question](http://drupal.org/node/916978) at drupal.org where i found some useful hints:

It seems to be an SQL-related issue ([described here](http://drupal.org/node/916978#comment-3881958)) not "solvable" with views2.

I'm now using the Reference view module (http://drupal.org/node/1319746) which allows to set up "child"-views (i.e. `features` and `extras`) I can include as fields in my original view (`vehicles`).